# Objectify multiple filters doesn´t work

Tags: google-app-engine, filter, objectify

ow can I filter using multiple attributes? (simulating an "AND" 
operation)

I have tried:

```
ofy().load().type(Produit.class).filter("idListe in",collectionProduits.getIdListes()).filter("supprime !=",true).list();
```

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class Produit implements  Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Index
    private Long idliste;
    @Index
    private Boolean supprime;

    public Produit() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Long getIdliste() {
        return idliste;
    }


    public void setIdliste(Long idliste) {
        this.idliste = idliste;
    }

    public Boolean getSupprime() {
        return supprime;
    }


    public void setSupprime(Boolean supprime) {
        this.supprime = supprime;
    }
```

I have this critical error:

> Uncaught exception from servlet java.io.IOException:
>   com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:
>   no matching index found. The suggested index for this query is:
>
> ```
> <datastore-index kind="Produit" ancestor="false" source="manual">
>     <property name="idliste" direction="asc"/>
>     <property name="supprime" direction="asc"/>
> </datastore-index>
> ```
>
> (through reference chain:
>   com.listecourses.model.CollectionProduits["produits"])    at
>   com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServletResponseResultWriter.writeValueAsString(ServletResponseResultWriter.java:187)
>     at
>   com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServletResponseResultWriter.write(ServletResponseResultWriter.java:74)
>     at
>   ....

After seeing this error, I changed my datastore-indexes.xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes  autoGenerate="false">
  <datastore-index kind="Produit" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="idliste" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="supprime" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

I re-deployed after creating this file. I waited a little bit of time for the index to generate. And I have the same error on log of appengine.

more, I have this error log on eclipse:

No projects found for [C:\workspace\example-AppEngine\war\datastore-indexes.xml]

Comment: The clue is in the error - have you tried adding the suggested [index](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes) to your `datastore-indexes.xml`?

Comment: I creat the datastore-indexes.xml in war directory.
this is my file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes  autoGenerate="false">
  <datastore-index kind="Produit" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="idliste" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="supprime" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>


But I have the same error.

Comment: Not an issue, happy to educate :)! (switching back to English since this has to do with your question and Stack is built for other users having similar issues, so I figure this is better handled in English, for posterity). Unless I'm mistaken, it needs to be in war/Web-inf, as per the docs here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig#Java_About_datastore-indexes_xml

Comment: thanks! it's work ! :-)